# using null-space for positivity

Tags: matrices, optimization, pseudoinverse

I have the rectangular matrix $M$ and its pseudoinverse $M^{-1}$ as well as a vector $v$.
Using them, I find the vector $w = M v$. Since $M$ is rectangular and thus noninvertible, there has to be ambiguity in this transformation, in the form of the null-space.

Given $v$ is positive in every component, is it possible to use the null-space to find positive vectors $w$ that could have come from the same $v$? I.e. given a $v \ | \ v_i \ge 0$ and its corresponding $w = M v$, find a $w' = w + \delta w$ such that $M^{-1} w' = v \ | \ \forall_i w'_i \gtrapprox  0$, where $\delta w$ is in the null-space?

I don't expect positive-semidefiniteness, but I'd like to get as close to that as possible.

In my concrete problem, $v \in R^3$ and $w \in R^{470}$ so the null-space should be rather large.

If there is a way to somehow *maximally* satisfy this, that would be even better. I.e. as extra constraint, maximize $\text{min } w'_i$ or something like that. I suppose that constraint alone would already give the above condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I was looking for are generalized barycentric coordinates, completely sidestepping the need for complicated optimization procedures. No explicit considerations of the null-space or any other such thing required at all.

This is quite specific to my problem here, but my code (in python) that does the trick, based on this paper [Barycentric Coordinates for Arbitrary Polygons in the Plane, Kai Hormann 2005
(pdf)](https://cgvr.cs.uni-bremen.de/papers/barycentric/barycentric.pdf) is:

```
import numpy as np

def barycentric(p, shape):
    n = shape.shape[0]
    s = shape - p
    r = np.zeros_like(shape[:, 0])
    a = np.zeros_like(shape[:, 0])
    d = np.zeros_like(shape[:, 0])
    w = np.zeros_like(shape[:, 0])
    for i in range(n):
        nxt = (i + 1) % n
        if (ri := np.linalg.norm(s[i])) == 0:
            w[i] = 1
            return w
        ai = np.cross(s[nxt], s[i])/2
        di = np.dot(s[nxt], s[i])
        if ai == 0 and di < 0:
            rip1 = np.linalg.norm(s[nxt])
            w[i] = ri/(ri+rip1)
            w[nxt] = rip1/(ri + rip1)
            return w
        r[i] = ri
        a[i] = ai
        d[i] = di
    for i in range(n):
        prv = (i + n - 1) % n
        nxt = (i + 1) % n
        if a[prv] != 0:
            w[i] += (r[prv] - d[prv]/r[i])/a[prv]
        if a[i] != 0:
            w[i] += (r[nxt] - d[i]/r[i])/a[i]
    return w / np.sum(w)
```

This is the part where your mileage may vary about whether this is actually a good solution:

Here, `shape` is a modified version of my matrix $M$ above. I dropped one column so it operates on 2D-vectors instead. For my vectors $v$ I first normalize them $v' = \frac{v}{\sum_i v_i}$ and then only use the first two components $v_{\mathbb{R}^2} = \left(v'_0, v'_1\right)$

I can later invert this transformation as needed so this is fine for my purposes.

These barycentric coordinates, corresponding to my $w$ above, are between 0 and 1 as long as I stay inside the shape defined by the rows of $M$, which is exactly what I was hoping for. Outside the shape, things may go negative, but that's fine for my purposes.

I'll accept this answer as it is what I'm looking for. However, if anybody wants to take a crack at the question as stated (which, I recognize, doesn't *quite* match what I'm doing here now), I'll probably switch to that answer instead.